# Processing video calling

Tags: video, random, processing

I'm currently in the process of making a code that will pull three random videos when a key is pressed.

For example, when the "A" key is pressed the code will randomly select one of three video files assigned to that key and play.

However, the problem at the moment is when I run the sketch I get the error "Could not load movie file 2" on the code line 35

1. myMovie = new Movie(this, ""+int(random(1, 3)));

   and the same for 1 and 3. I have made it so the sketch would play each video individually to see if it was a problem with the video files but it still couldn't find any of the files. The videos were imported through Sketch and Add file and they are found in the sketchbook file under data.

If anyone could help out I would greatly appreciate it,
thank you. :)

```java
import processing.video.*; 
boolean valid=false; 
String[] one = {  

"1.mp4", "2.mp4", "3.mov", "4.mov", "5.mov", "6.mov",   "7.mov",
"8.mov", "9.mov" };

 Movie myMovie;    
 
 int a = 0; 
 float md = 0; 
 float mt = 0;   

 void setup() {   
 size(400, 400, P2D); 
 }
 
 void draw() 
 {   
   if (valid){
    image(myMovie, 0, 0, width, height);   
    }   
 }   
 
 void keyPressed() 
 {
 if (key == 'a' || key == 'A')  
   {
    valid=true;
    myMovie = new Movie(this, ""+int(random(1, 3)));
    myMovie.play();   }
 else if (key == 's' || key == 'S')   
 {
   valid=true;
   myMovie = new Movie(this, ""+int(random(4, 6)));
   myMovie.play();   }
 else if (key == 'd' || key == 'D')   
 {
   valid=true;
   myMovie = new Movie(this, ""+int(random(7, 9)));
   myMovie.play();   }
 else   
 {
    myMovie.stop();   }
```

}

my apologise for the layout of the code I was unsure how to properly copy and paste the code into this comment.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```java
myMovie = new Movie(this, ""+int(random(1, 3)));
```

Should be this:

```java
myMovie = new Movie(this, int(random(1, 3)) + ".mov");
```

You could also get the filename from the array:

```java
myMovie = new Movie(this, one[int(random(1, 3))]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response :)

I tried this out and I get the error "Could not load movie file2.mov"

is this because the code is calling for a file named file2.mov ?

Comment: It seems that this calls and plays the video, however I can only hear the audio on each file and the screen is white. Getting closer though!

Comment: @SamLeighCookson The point of my answer is that you need to be sure about what file you're looking for. Before you were looking for a file named `2`, which is obviously not right. Consider printing out the value before calling the `new Movie()` constructor. But yeah, it sounds like you're loading the file now. You might consider asking a new question if you're having other issues. Good luck!